# Shadow in Firefox in Full Screen - MacOS

Tags: macos, firefox

There is an interesting and annoying behavior in my Firefox. I couldn't find a report in the Firefox forums and hoping to have an answer here.

When I make my Firefox full screen (desktop) in my Mac, there is a shadow-like layer on the top left corner.

[image]

However, it's not there when it's not full-screen.

[image]

Even weirder is that when I click on the search bar, part of the search bar that is supposed to be affected by the shadow, it's normal.

[image]

And it's not my whole screen as I have no problem with any other app/desktop.

[image]

I tried with different monitors and it's happening in all of them regardless of resolution, connection etc.

Is there someone encountering the same problem and know a solution for this as it's super annoying?

MacOs Version: Ventura 13.5.2

Mac: Macbook Pro 14" 2021 M1 Pro

Firefox: 117.0 (64 Bit)